# Disable HTTP GET for some pages php

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, wamp

I want to disable HTTP GET method for some of my php pages in my website. Can I do it in php code?

Lets suppose I have two pages **a.html** and **action.php**. Now **a.html** is normal page can be accessed with any method and it submits the information to **action.php**. But I want that information submitted to **action.php** can only be submitted through post method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Send a Method Not Allowed header along with some explanatory text (preferably something friendlier and more useful then my example below).

Exit afterwards so you don't continue processing with the regular page.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
  header('Method Not Allowed', true, 405);
  echo "GET method requests are not accepted for this resource";
  exit;
}
```

You might want to consider white listing (and testing for the absence of methods you do accept) instead of black listing GET. (Since you might not want PUT, DELETE, etc either).

Answer (score 1):

Put the code below at the beginning.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
  header('Location: a.html');
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the current method and redirect the user if it is GET.